# Inclusion Tags in Django on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

I want to create a reusable template (almost like a UserControl from the .NET world) that I can apply in multiple places, something like:

```
{% for thing in things %}
    {% render_thing thing %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where render_thing is my custom inclusion tag. My Python code reads as follows:

```
def get_full_path(relative_path):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), relative_path)

def render_thing(thing):
    return {'thing':thing }

register = template.create_template_register()
register.inclusion_tag(get_full_path('thing.html'))(render_thing)
```

Where thing.html is my little template. However, when I run this I get the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'render_thing'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?  The current default on app engine is pretty old - 0.96.

Comment: right, I tried adding the `use_library('django','1.2')` code but it errored saying it didn't recognise use_library :(

Comment: oops, forgot the import. Interesting, fixed that - now have a new error `TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'render_activity', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Django 1.2 templates, you will need to supply a Python module-style reference to your custom tag code rather than a file path.

There's a [full description of the problem and the solution on my blog](http://blog.adamcrossland.net/post/show/fixing-custom-tags-with-django-12).

EDIT:
Sorry to be so high-level on you. Here's a more step-by-step explanation:

1. Put your custom tag code in a file, say `my_custom_tags.py` for the sake of example.
2. take the .py file that your custom tag code lives in and put it in a subdirectory of your main AppEngine project directory, say `customtags` for the sake of an example.
3. in that new subdirectory, create an empty file that has the name `__init__.py`
4. in your AppEngine application's main `.py` file, add this code:

   from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
   template.register_template_library('customtags.my_custom_tags')

All of the custom tags defined in your custom tag library should now be available in your template files with no additional work.

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm afraid that doesn't really help. It might help a Python/GAE ninja but I really have no idea what I need to do to get started.

Comment: @ConfusedNoob; I added more explicit steps. Hope that helps.

Comment: i managed to crack it myself but I think your answer will be very helpful to others in my situation, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

load template tag

```
{% load my_template_library %}
```

see manual

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/
- http://www.mechanicalgirl.com/view/custom-template-tags-in-django/
- http://www.protocolostomy.com/2009/08/05/practial-django-projects-custom-template-tags-and-updates-on-linuxlaboratory/

Comment: This isn't actually necessary if you follow the steps outlined by Adam.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the templatetag library within each template that uses it.

```
{% load my_template_library %}
```